# Why is this not "Not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I asked ["How do I force MATLAB to run deep learning code on the CPU instead of the GPU?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310280/how-to-force-matlab-to-run-a-deep-learning-code-on-cpu-instead-of-gpu), and the answer is ["MATLAB needs a GPU"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310280/how-to-force-matlab-to-run-a-deep-learning-code-on-cpu-instead-of-gpu/37317121#37317121). This is obviously not an answer, because it is stating the obvious. As stated in comments, there should be an answer.

My question is: Why is a "not-an-answer" flag rejected? I cannot see details of disputation.

Comment: Disputed means the community aka review disagreed with your flag.

Comment: my question is why they disagree?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: [apples and oranges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: ok, now I see even a partial explanation is acceptable as an answer. This is somehow unfair in my opinion. but anyway rules is rules.

Comment: Why is that unfair? Keep in mind that we are not answering *your* question, we are answering a question that we think is interesting for future visitors. For those visitors partial answers might have value. Down voting is a much better moderation option because with flags you're trying to delete stuff and we hate to delete anything of possible value.

Comment: @rene if anything interesting for future visitors can be considered as an answer, then each single comment can be an answer itself. isn't it? each of them have some valuable information.

Comment: Some comments are indeed valuable to help make the question or answer clearer. In an ideal world comments should disappear after that. And sometimes the best answer is in a comment, yes. Either the OP or someone else is happy to move that to an answer so proper voting can start.

Answer (score 9):

> This is obviously not an answer because it is stating the obvious.

That would mean that you feel it's not a *correct* answer.  That doesn't make it "Not An Answer".  It makes it a failed attempt at answering the question.

You should downvote answers that you feel attempt, but fail, to answer the question.

The Not An Answer flag is for posts that aren't even *attempting* to answer the question.

Comment: I am still saying it is not an answer because it is not even attempting to answer. My question is "how can I overcome the limitation?" and the answer is " the limitation is blablabla" .

Comment: @Woeitg You asked how to perform a given action using a CPU, and you were given the answer that you can't, because there's a requirement that you need to have a GPU.  That you don't like the answer doesn't make it not an answer.  (In fact, it doesn't even make it an incorrect answer.)

Comment: @Servy Well, if the comment about a workaround can be made into a valid and working answer, I'd say this one counts as an incorrect answer.

Comment: @mrLister which brings it back to "it attempts to answer but it's wrong, so downvote"